# Gluon Maven tool chain builds app, but Gradle tool chain does not (fails linking)

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I have been using the Gluon tool chain to compile a JavaFX app into native images for both Mac OS X (Sonoma, M1) and iOS.

It all works great. Got it working end to end. Great tool chain!

But ...

I have been using Maven to do the builds, using the standard Gluon maven setup.

I now thought I would try to build using Gradle, using the Gradle "com.gluonhq.gluonfx-gradle-plugin" plugin, version 1.0.21.

Using this plugin the code compiles just fine, but when it comes to the linking phase I get this warning (and the link fails):

```
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] ld: warning: object file (/Users/graham/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home/lib/svm/clibraries/darwin-aarch64/libdarwin.a[2](foundation.o)) was built for newer 'macOS' version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] ld: Undefined symbols:
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]   _LMGetKbdType, referenced from:
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]       _getJavaCodeForMacKeyAndModifiers in libglass.a[14](GlassKey.obj)
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]   _TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource, referenced from:
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]       _getJavaCodeForMacKey in libglass.a[14](GlassKey.obj)
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]   _TISGetInputSourceProperty, referenced from:
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]       _getJavaCodeForMacKeyAndModifiers in libglass.a[14](GlassKey.obj)
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]   _kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData, referenced from:
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]       _getJavaCodeForMacKeyAndModifiers in libglass.a[14](GlassKey.obj)
[Mon Nov 20 10:53:17 NZDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It feels like the Maven plugin is detecting some environment variable, or path, that the Gradle plugin isn't. But I haven't been able to work out what it is.

[I actually get the warning with Maven, but it doesn't stop the linking]

Anyone have any idea what I am missing?
thx

Comment: If I take it right, using the same project, GluonFX Maven plugin 1.0.21 works, but GluonFX Gradle plugin 1.0.21 fails?

Comment: Yes its the same project. The only difference is using the gradle build scripts rather than the Maven ones.

Comment: Gradle plugin works fine for me, I can't reproduce your issue. Make sure you don't have any gradle property set pointing to an old JDK, JavaFX, GraalVM version. You can also try to clean up caches: ~/.gluon/substrate, ~/.gradle, ~/.openjfx (carefully of course), and try again.

Comment: Hi Jose. Are you on Sonoma, or an early version of Mac OS X? Just trying to eliminate one possible difference in our setups.

Comment: Sonoma 14.1.1, M1 as well.

Comment: The weird thing about this issue is that Maven issues a similar warning, but it doesn't cause the process to stop. My maven output says "[SUB] ld: warning: object file (/Users/graham/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home/lib/svm/clibraries/darwin-aarch64/libdarwin.a[2](foundation.o)) was built for newer 'macOS' version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)"

Comment: I might have fixed this issue. The missing symbols appear to all be in Carbon I added the following to my gradle build `linkerArgs = ["-Wl,-framework,Carbon"]`  and I no longer have the problem. Perhaps the Maven plugin automatically links against Carbon, but the gradle plugin does not?

Comment: No, neither Maven plugin nor Substrate, which is used also by the Gradle plugin, use Carbon. I suggest you have a look at the link logs from both plugins, you should get the exact same command line (look for `PB Command for link: gcc`...). Can you spot any difference?

Comment: Commenting on my own comment above. Adding Carbon is a dumb idea -- only works on Mac. I have found the issue. I had set `javafxStaticSdkVersion` and `javaStaticSdkVersion` in my Gradle build but not my Maven build. Removed that and all is good